# How to convert straight normal quotes to smart quotes in php?

Tags: php

How to convert straight normal quotes to smart quotes in php using string replace.

```
<?php
function convert_smart_quotes($string)
{
    $search = '&quot;';

    $replace = array('&ldquo;','&rdquo;');

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
}

echo convert_smart_quotes('"Smaple Text"');
?>
```

Comment: In `"Smaple Text"` there're no `&quot;`, there are `"`. These are __different__ searches.

Comment: Problem solved....Thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use preg_replace and search for word boundaries.

```
// smart quotes..
$text = preg_replace('~"\b~', '&ldquo;', $text);
$text = preg_replace('~\b"~', '&rdquo;', $text);
// everything else
$text = str_replace('"', '&quot;', $text);
```

or if you want to combine the smartquote replacement in a singe regex

```
$text = preg_replace('~"\b(.*?)\b"~', '&ldquo;$1&rdquo;', $text);
```